# Some questions about Redigo and concurrency

Tags: go, redigo

I have read through the whole Redigo documentation which can be found here.
https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#pkg-variables

Here the documentation clearly states that connections do not support concurrent calls to Send(), Flush() or Receive() methods.

> Connections do not support concurrent calls to the write methods
>   (Send, Flush) or concurrent calls to the read method (Receive).
>   Connections do allow a concurrent reader and writer.

And then it states that since the Do method can be a combination of Send(), Flush() and Receive(), we can't use Do() concurrently (with) the other methods.

> Because the Do method combines the functionality of Send, Flush and
>   Receive, the  Do method cannot be called concurrently with the other
>   methods.

Does this mean that we can use Do() concurrently alone using a single connection stored in a global variable as long as we don't mix it with the other methods?

For example like this:

```
var (

    // Redis Conn.
    redisConn redis.Conn

    // Redis PubSubConn wraps a Conn with convenience methods for subscribers.
    redisPsc redis.PubSubConn
)

func redisInit() {

    c, err := redis.Dial(config.RedisProtocol, config.RedisAddress)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    c.Do("AUTH", config.RedisPass)
    redisConn = c

    c, err = redis.Dial(config.RedisProtocol, config.RedisAddress)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    c.Do("AUTH", config.RedisPass)
    redisPsc = redis.PubSubConn{c}

    for {
        switch v := redisPsc.Receive().(type) {
        case redis.Message:
            // fmt.Printf("%s: message: %s\n", v.Channel, v.Data)
            socketHub.broadcast <- v.Data
        case redis.Subscription:
            // fmt.Printf("%s: %s %d\n", v.Channel, v.Kind, v.Count)
        case error:
            log.Println(v)
        }
    }

}
```

And then calling the Do() method inside some go routine like this:

```
if _, err = redisConn.Do("PUBLISH", fmt.Sprintf("user:%d", fromId), message); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
if _, err = redisConn.Do("PUBLISH", fmt.Sprintf("user:%d", toId), message); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

And then later the document says that for full concurrent access to Redis, we need to create a pool and get connections from the pool and release them when we are done with it.

Does this mean that I can use, Send(), Flush() and Receive() as I want, as long as I get a connection from the pool? So in other words every time I need to do something in a go routine I have to get a new connection from the pool instead of reusing a global connection? And does this mean that I can use the Do() method with for example Send() as long as I get a new connection from the pool?

So to sum up:

1) Can I use the Do() method concurrently as long as I do not use it with the Send, Flush and Receive methods?

2) Can I use everything as I want as long as I get a new connection from the pool and release it when I'm done?

3) If (1) is true, does this affect performance? Is it better to use a global connection concurrently with only using the Do() method as in the provided example by me, and not mixing things up with Send, Flush and Receive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have one concurrent writer and one concurrent reader. Because `Do` combines read and write operations, you can have one current current call to `Do`.  To put this another way, you cannot call `Do` concurrently.  You cannot store a connection in a global variable and call `Do` without protecting the connection with a mutex or using some other mechanism to ensure that there is no more than one concurrent caller to `Do`.

Pools support concurrent access. The connections returned by the pool `Get` method follow the rules for concurrency as described above. To get full concurrent access to the database, the application should within a single goroutine do the following:  `Get` a connection from the pool; execute Redis commands on the connection;  `Close` the connection to return the underlying resources to the pool.

Replace `redisConn redis.Conn` with a pool. Initialize the pool at app startup:

```
 var redisPool *redis.Pool

 ...

redisPool = &redis.Pool{
    MaxIdle: 3,  // adjust to your needs
    IdleTimeout: 240 * time.Second,  // adjust to your needs
    Dial: func () (redis.Conn, error) {
        c, err := redis.Dial(config.RedisProtocol, config.RedisAddress)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        if _, err := c.Do("AUTH", config.RedisPass); err != nil {
            c.Close()
            return nil, err
        }
        return c, err
    },
}
```

Use the pool to publish to the channels:

```
 c := redisPool.Get()
 if _, err = c.Do("PUBLISH", fmt.Sprintf("user:%d", fromId), message); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
 }
 if _, err = c.Do("PUBLISH", fmt.Sprintf("user:%d", toId), message); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
 }
 c.Close()
```

Do not initialize the pool in `redisInit()`. There's no guarantee that `redisInit()` will execute before other code in the application uses the pool.

Also add a call to [Subscribe](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#PubSubConn.Subscribe) or [PSubscribe](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#PubSubConn.PSubscribe).

Comment: I run redisInit() concurrently like "go redisInit()", and I have two connections. One redisConn redis.Conn to do publish commands an one redisPsc redis.PubSubConn to subscribe and unsubscribe.

Comment: I am not using a pool currently. But if I understood correctly I can not use Do(), to Publish stuff, because when I publish stuff I also receive with the same command concurrently?

Comment: If the app publishes from a single goroutine, then the code in the question can be used as is.  The PUBLISH command works like the other regular Redis commands: the app sends a command and the server sends a response. `Do` sends a command and receives the response.  If the app publishes from multiple goroutines, then protect redisConn with a mutex or use a pool as described in my answer.

Comment: The app uses publish from a "websocket readpump", so it is happening everytime a websocket message arrives.

Comment: You should use a pool.  The [pool documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#Pool) describes how to use a pool with HTTP request handlers (which your websocket reader starts as).